# Pymongo ignoring allowDiskUse = True

Tags: python, mongodb, debugging, pymongo

I've looked at the other answers to this question, and yet it is still not working. I am trying to delete duplicate cases, here is the function:

```
def deleteDups(datab):
    col = db[datab]
    pipeline = [
    {'$group': {
        '_id': {
            'CASE NUMBER': '$CASE NUMBER',
            'JURISDICTION': '$JURISDICTION'},#needs to be case insensitive
            'count': {'$sum': 1},
            'ids': {'$push': '$_id'}
            }
        },
    {'$match': {'count': {'$gt': 1}}},
    ]
    results = col.aggregate(pipeline, allowDiskUse = True)
    count = 0
    for result in results:
        doc_count = 0
        print(result)
        it = iter(result['ids'])
        next(it)
        for id in it:
            deleted = col.delete_one({'_id': id})
            count += 1
            doc_count += 1
            #print("API call recieved:", deleted.acknowledged) debug, is the database recieving requests
            
    print("Total documents deleted:", count)
```

And yet, every time, I get this traceback:

```
  File "C:\Users\*****\Documents\GitHub\*****\controller.py", line 202, in deleteDups
    results = col.aggregate(pipeline, allowDiskUse = True)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\pymongo\collection.py", line 2375, in aggregate
    return self._aggregate(_CollectionAggregationCommand,
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\pymongo\collection.py", line 2297, in _aggregate
    return self.__database.client._retryable_read(
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 1464, in _retryable_read
    return func(session, server, sock_info, slave_ok)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\pymongo\aggregation.py", line 136, in get_cursor
    result = sock_info.command(
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\pymongo\pool.py", line 603, in command
    return command(self.sock, dbname, spec, slave_ok,
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\pymongo\network.py", line 165, in command
    helpers._check_command_response(
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\pymongo\helpers.py", line 159, in _check_command_response
    raise OperationFailure(msg % errmsg, code, response)
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: Exceeded memory limit for $group, but didn't allow external sort. Pass allowDiskUse:true to opt in.
```

I asterisked out bits of path to protect privacy. But it is driving me absolutely nuts that this line: `results = col.aggregate(pipeline, allowDiskUse = True)` very explicitly passes allowDiskUse = True, and Mongo is just ignoring it. If I misspelled something, I'm blind. True has to be capitalized to pass a bool in python.

I feel like I'm going crazy here.

Comment: what is the role of the user you type in the connection string? and maybe include the dbPath?

Comment: I'm an admin. The db variable is correct, the code runs fine on a smaller collection.

Comment: Yes but you also need privileges to create a `_tmp` folder

Comment: Which questions did you review? Also link to driver documentation showing correct usage.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/free-shared-limitations#operational-limitations):

> Atlas Free Tier and shared clusters do not support the allowDiskUse option for the aggregation command or its helper method.

(Thanks to [Shane Harvey](https://developer.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/pymongo-ignoring-allowdiskuse-true/12066/5) for this info)